# Oracle : How to lock the rows using for update in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please anyone guide me samples for oracle **for update** attributes for row level locking purpose. please give me sample sql. thanks in advance

Comment: you can google that and you will have plenty results

Comment: How about reading the Oracle documentation, or doing a google search.  Don't be lazy.

Comment: no no guys am tried but its not working am new for oracle and so have done plenty of samples i didnt get the clear results

Comment: @Kowthalganesh If you have already tried something, please post your code along with any useful information.

Comment: select * from dept

select * from dept for update wait 10

insert into dept values('2','ece','madurai')

Comment: now any one can explain how to use for update in sub query or nested query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanx for your support, i had done a mistake, i will run the for update in same session that is the problem it wont affect the row level becoz of same thread process, using two different thread i mean sessions it will work fine.